# Wordpress Rest API - parameters for multiple tags

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, tags, filtering

I need to pull categories 8,9,10 and filter the result by tags 11 **AND** 12. If I make a call as below, it it filtering either by tag 11 **OR** tag 12 - Instead of AND. Can anyone help and suggest how I can call so that it is filtered by both tags?

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags=11,12&categories=8,9,10